# TypeScript error when I set initial state in redux-toolkit createSlice method

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I have some interfaces in redux-models.ts file:

```
export interface IUser{
    user:{}
}
export interface IUsers{
    users:IUser[]
}
export type TUser=IUser|IUsers
```

And I have called interfaces in todoSlice.ts file:

```
import { createSlice,PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { TUser,IUser,IUsers } from "./redux-models";


const initialState:TUser={
    user:{},
    users:[]
}
const slice=createSlice({
    name:"slice",
    initialState:{initialState},
    reducers:{
        setUsers(state,action:PayloadAction<IUsers>){
            state.users=action.payload;
        }
    }

})
```

But The typescript compile wont let me continue due to error:

```
Property 'users' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ initialState: TUser; }>'.ts(2339)
```

**Note:(Error happened when I set state.users)**

What was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On interface IUser you don't have 'users', that error has happened because you wrote `IUser | IUsers` (also in the IUsers you don't have 'user').

You can try this:

```
export type TUser = IUser & IUsers
```